# How to Embed Google Plus Write a Review

Tags: javascript, api, plugins, google-plus, review

Does anyone know if there is a way to allow visitors on your site to leave a review **directly** on your personal webpage, without having to redirect them to your Google+ Local Page, without making them click anything extra?

Ideally it would just be an embedded plugin, just like the Google+ Recommend Button, or Facebook Like... but instead of liking/sharing/following - display the star rating selector, and a textarea. And, when someone fills it out, and presses publish, it will post directly to your Google+ Local Page.

I am not interested in showing existing reviews/testimonials. I just want people to be able to write the review right then and there without leaving my page.

This would be on a custom CMS (not WordPress, or Shopify, or anything of that sort), but a hard coded HTML page.

I have been looking for API or any other method, but it seems that no such thing exists as far as I can tell.

I would prefer not to write an explanation of how someone has to go to Google+ and Log in (or create an account), then find my local page, then click write a review, then.... blah blah blah.

Can we just skip ALL of that, and have them write it without any extra steps (anonymously, not anonymously, doesn't matter). I don't want to pander to my customers about how it would mean a lot for them to write a review or anything of that sort. I just want them to see that the option is available, and decide for themselves.

Has anyone ever heard of this being done?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the review sites e.g. google, facebook, yelp, have stopped allowing api access to submit reviews. Google plus doesn't even allow reviews at all anymore. It all goes through google places which also doesn't allow api access to leave a review.

Best bet it to create a link from each review site and direct the use to the site as direct as possible.

Google even has a page setup to show you how to create the review link: [Google review link help](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772?hl=en)

example google review link: [google Sydney review](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20sydney&*&lrd=0x6b12ae37b47f5b37:0x8eaddfcd1b32ca52,3,5)